# Issue with Jetty Http2 Client

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty, http2, jetty-9

I m getting below exception with Jetty 9.4.19 Http2 Client. The server is a Spring boot application ( 2.1.8 release ) running on Jetty

```
Request failed: java.io.IOException: protocol_error/invalid_hpack_block
at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP2.onFailure(HttpReceiverOverHTTP2.java:184)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Stream.notifyFailure(HTTP2Stream.java:611)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Stream.onFailure(HTTP2Stream.java:361)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Stream.process(HTTP2Stream.java:267)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Session.onStreamFailure(HTTP2Session.java:513) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.parser.Parser$Listener$Wrapper.onStreamFailure(Parser.java:404)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.parser.BodyParser.notifyStreamFailure(BodyParser.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.parser.BodyParser.streamFailure(BodyParser.java:228) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.parser.HeaderBlockParser.parse(HeaderBlockParser.java:106) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.parser.HeadersBodyParser.parse(HeadersBodyParser.java:172) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.parser.Parser.parseBody(Parser.java:194) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:123) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Connection$HTTP2Producer.produce(HTTP2Connection.java:248) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produceTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:357) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:181) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:132) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Connection.produce(HTTP2Connection.java:170) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Connection.onFillable(HTTP2Connection.java:125) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Connection$FillableCallback.succeeded(HTTP2Connection.java:348) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:427) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:321) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:159) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:781) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:917) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
```

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The above exception is coming when the client is trying to read the response, the request got processed successfully on the server.  There is mTLS between the Client and Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server has sent an invalid HPACK block, as the exception reports.

What server it is? Tomcat?

You will get more details about what the client considers wrong if you enable DEBUG logging for the Jetty `HTTP2Client`, by setting the category `org.eclipse.jetty.http2` to `DEBUG`.

Likely the server sent down an invalid header or something similar.

Since you're based on Spring Boot, you can enable Jetty on the server side too (if not already), as shown [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html) and see if the problem still happens.

Comment: The server is running on Jetty.  I will enable DEBUG logs for "org.eclipse.jetty.http2" package on the client-side and update the thread.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with the headers, I'll need to figure out that but I have skipped sending headers from the server and i m not seeing the error.  Thanks a lot

Comment: Certain HTTP headers are forbidden by HTTP/2, but if the application was setting them, the Jetty server was not filtering them out. This was issue [#3956](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/3956) and fixed in Jetty 9.4.21 (at this time, staged for release but not yet released).

Comment: The problem is because of a pseudo-header. Pseudo header ":status" was added to the regular headers block and that is causing the issue. The reason for this, the Http2 spring boot based server is proxying the request to another Http2 server and returning the headers that are sent by the proxied server.

Comment: have same issue after bumping spring boot version, but also tried latest 9.4.21 jetty, but still have exception like `Caused by: java.io.IOException: cancel_stream_error`

Comment: Pseudo headers such as `:status` are fixed by [#4115](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/4115) in Jetty 9.4.22 - the sender will get an exception trying to set them.

Comment: great to know, waiting for release ;D